# How to get Redis Enterprise Cloud URL on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, redis

I installed Redis Enterprise Cloud on my dyno on Heroku for the first time and didn't find any config in settings as described in the docs

```
Once Redise Cloud has been added, you will notice a REDISCLOUD_URL config vars in your heroku config containing the username, password, hostname and port of your first Redis Cloud database.
```

How can I get the `REDISCLOUD_URL` config after it's installing this addon?

Answer (score 0):

Check the getting started doc:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#getting-started

```sh
$ heroku config:get REDISCLOUD_URL
```